# ES6 Proxy logs an unexplainable extra value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

So far I have understood ES6 proxies as a way to add intercepts to allow you to add custom behavior to your code. Implemented this code snippet to intercept a push into an array but it logs an extra the extra 'trapped! 1' after a push and I cannot figure out why. Does anyone know why it does this? And does this mean the code in the  trap is run twice?

```js
const handler = {
  set(target, propertyKey, value, receiver) {
    console.log('trapped!', value);
    return Reflect.set(target, propertyKey, value, receiver);
  }
};

const p = new Proxy([], handler);
p.push('a')
```

Comment: try logging the propertyKey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's setting the length as well as the index of the array you're pushing onto. That's why it runs twice for every push.

```
let handler = {
  set(target, propertyKey, value, receiver) {
    console.log(`set ${propertyKey} to ${value}`)
    return Reflect.set(target, propertyKey, value, receiver);
  }
};

const p = new Proxy([], handler);
p.push('a')
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. The 2nd logged number value increases by one with every push. Is there anyway to avoid it running twice if the target is an array?

Comment: From your comment i just realized I can use the propertyKey to make sure any custom code in the function is run once. Thanks